# Description Resource Path Location Type invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'uint32_t {aka long unsigned int}')

Tags: c, pointers

Why do I get this error on sum = line ?
Not sure what is wrong...
mem_ptr is declared as pointer...

```
uint32_t MCU_ReadMemTest(uint32_t start_addr, uint32_t end_addr)
    {
          uint32_t mem_ptr = (uint32_t*)start_addr;
          uint32_t stop_ptr = (uint32_t*)end_addr;

          while (mem_ptr != stop_ptr)
          {
              sum = (*mem_ptr);
              mem_ptr++;
              cnt++;
          }

          return retval;
    }
```

Thanks,
R.

Comment: You say that "mem_ptr is declared as pointer", the declaration is `uint32_t mem_ptr`. I.e. you *don't* declare `mem_ptr` as a pointer.

Comment: You're missing a `*` after `uint32_t` for both `mem_ptr` and `stop_ptr`. Whether that's a typo or a misunderstanding, I don't know. And where are the declarations for `sum`, `cnt` and `retval`?

Comment: thanks for comments, yes, thought that the second * declares as pointer, but was wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help,

have changed the code and now it is ok...

```
uint32_t MCU_ReadMemTest(uint32_t start_addr, uint32_t end_addr)
{
      uint32_t retval, startt, endt, cnt=0,sum=0;
      uint32_t *mem_ptr = start_addr;
      uint32_t *stop_ptr = end_addr;
...
```

Thanks,
R.